Spring Security 5 -> 6 upgrade - not matching requests
I'm migrating an existing enterprise webapp from Spring 5 to 6 and Spring Security 5.8 to 6.3. Here are the intercept-url mappings in our security-context.xml file (yes, we're still using an xml file - we're slowly working our way to modern best practices):
    <http entry-point-ref="restAuthenticationEntryPoint" realm="Protected" pattern="/**" use-expressions="true" authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager">
        <intercept-url pattern="/v1.2/rest/login" access="permitAll()" requires-channel="https" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/v1.2/rest/i18n" access="permitAll()" requires-channel="https" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/v1.2/rest/sites/local" access="permitAll()" requires-channel="any" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/v1.2/rest/cntl/state" access="permitAll()" requires-channel="any" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/v1.2/rest/swagger.json" access="permitAll()" requires-channel="any" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/index.html" access="permitAll()" requires-channel="any" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/v1.2/dictionaries/**" access="permitAll()" requires-channel="any" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/v1.2/rest/admins/**" access="isFullyAuthenticated()" requires-channel="https" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/v1.2/rest/**" access="isFullyAuthenticated()" requires-channel="https" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/jmx/**" access="hasRole('SUPPORT')" requires-channel="https" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/objectives/**" access="permitAll()" requires-channel="https" />
        <custom-filter ref="basicAuthenticationFilter" position="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <form-login default-target-url="/index.html" authentication-details-source-ref="authenticationDetailsSource" />
        <logout invalidate-session="true" logout-url="/v1.2/rest/logout" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" success-handler-ref="logoutHandler" />
        <csrf disabled="true" />
        <x509 subject-principal-regex="(.*)" />
    </http>

The webapp base url is /mgmt, so requests are made to /mgmt/v1.2/rest/...
I'm noticing when debugging the SS6 RequestMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager loop that my requests are not matching any of the intercept mappings. When I compare this to the way it works in SS5 (the same loop exists, but it's in a different location), it finds the correct match.
I've searched the SS migration guides and can find no indication that things have to be done differently in these intercept-url mappings. This tells me (from experience) that we've probably been doing it wrong for a long time and older versions are simply more permissive than Spring Security 6.3.
On the other hand, I've examined the Spring Security documentation as well, and it seems to me what we're doing here is correct. I could find no documentation, however, on the attributes of the http tag - I'm sure it's out there - I'm just missing it.
If anyone has any insights it would be much appreciated.
